# How to solve npm missing script: Build and host my react application?

Tags: reactjs, host, netlify

I am trying to host my react application with Netlify but when I run npm run build I have this error

```
npm ERR! missing script: build
```

This is my package.json file

```
 "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Your package.json file must be in the root directory of the project. Otherwise you can set the root path in netlify

Answer (score 0):

When Netlify runs `npm`, it is unable to find the `run` command in your `package.json`, most likely because it is in the wrong directory.

Your `package.json` needs to be in the [Base directory](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/get-started/#definitions) in your Netlify config.